grouping dot-separated string list
Group dot-separated string to fixed format
In the input, I got the array of the next lines that represent some tree structure:
    "323-060",
    "323-060.040",
    "323-060.040.030",    
    "323-060.088",
    "323-060.088.020",    
    "323-060.010",
    "323-060.010.080",
    "323-060.010.080.020",
    "323-060.010.080.060"

It's tree structue:
"323-060" - the root
And this tree has the next hierarchy
323-060   /*rot*/
        040       /*second level, full path: 323-060.040*/
            030   /* third level, full path: 323-060.040.303 */
        088
            020

As a result, I have to get the next list grouped:
"323-060\323-060.040\323-060.040.030"
"323-060\323-060.088\323-060.088.020"
"323-060\323-060.010\323-060.010.080\323-060.010.080.020"
"323-060\323-060.010\323-060.010.080\323-060.010.080.060"

How to do it in Java ?

I think your inputs and outputs need formatting. As it is, it is incomprehensible what you want. In some places it also seems like you are missing a few quotation marks

As @Asmir mentioned your question is difficult to understand the end goal you want to achieve. Please reformat your code correctly. Consider adding as many details as possible

Read input, parse input string, put like strings on the same line, write output lines.

Explain what is the criteria for grouping and show it with examples. Don't expect people just to deduce it from an example output.

In the code below Node class represents each node in tree. buildTree() method create the tree from input by spliting each string by dots to get parts. And HashMap is for  keeping track of nodes by their full path. For each part we check if the node exists in map if not we create a new one. Inside  generatePaths() method we recursively traverse tree to create expected output.
package org.example;

import java.util.*;

public class GroupString {
    static class Node {
        String value;
        List<Node> children;

        Node(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {
                "323-060",
                "323-060.040",
                "323-060.040.030",
                "323-060.088",
                "323-060.088.020",
                "323-060.010",
                "323-060.010.080",
                "323-060.010.080.020",
                "323-060.010.080.060"
        };

        Node root = buildTree(input);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        generatePaths(root, new ArrayList<>(), result);

        for (String path : result) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }

    private static Node buildTree(String[] input) {
        Map<String, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        Node root = null;

        for (String path : input) {
            String[] parts = path.split("\\.");
            StringBuilder currentPath = new StringBuilder();
            Node parent = null;

            for (String part : parts) {
                if (currentPath.length() > 0) {
                    currentPath.append(".");
                }
                currentPath.append(part);
                String key = currentPath.toString();

                Node currentNode = nodeMap.getOrDefault(key, new Node(key));
                nodeMap.putIfAbsent(key, currentNode);

                if (parent != null) {
                    if (!parent.children.contains(currentNode)) {
                        parent.children.add(currentNode);
                    }
                } else {
                    root = currentNode;
                }

                parent = currentNode;
            }
        }

        return root;
    }

    private static void generatePaths(Node node, List<String> path, List<String> result) {
        if (node == null) return;

        path.add(node.value);

        if (node.children.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(String.join("\\", path));
        } else {
            for (Node child : node.children) {
                generatePaths(child, new ArrayList<>(path), result);
            }
        }
    }
}


Perfect!!! Thank ouy

Good to see that the answer is accurate, I would appreciate if you could accept it well.
